# Unicode Decryption

Tags: python, encoding

I've read that the Unicode encryption encompasses all other character encrpytions, but why do I get an error when trying this. I know I can decode with Latin but Unicode should be a superset.

```
'été'.decode('utf-8')
```

Comment: Unicode is not an encryption (or even an *encoding*) at all.  You (and every programmer) should read http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell Python the encoding of your source file:

```
# coding=utf-8
a = 'été'.decode('utf-8')
print a
```

See [PEP 263](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/) for more details.  Here's a relevant snippet:

> To define a source code encoding, a magic comment must
>       be placed into the source files either as first or second
>       line in the file